# Why is ajax request not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have been having a hell of a time with asp.net and ajax request using JQuery. I cannot figure out why the following does not work. Am I missing something? It seems to fire off the request ok (no errors), but it never goes inside the method.

```
 // asp.net webforms (NOT MVC)
public partial class PollManager : System.Web.UI.Page
{

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod]
        public static string DeletePoll(string pollId)
        {
            string test = "testing";

            return test;
        }
}


  **Updated Code**

  $.ajax({
        url: "PollManager.aspx/DeletePoll",
        data: { "pollId": "17" },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }                
    });
```

In the master page there is a `<asp:toolkitscriptmanager>`, I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you edit your question to post more code about the sever side?  Is this an MVC page? Is it a Web Forms app?  If its MVC can you post the routes you have set up?

Comment: It looks like a web service to me, not what I would think of as a Web Form.

Comment: Notice how the class inherits from the Page Class...

Answer (score 0):

Well... for one `data: "17"` isn't going to work.  You'd need to do something like `data: {"pollId" : "17"}`

Comment: Still doesn't go into the server-side method on debug

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are mixing up ASP.NET web services, and ASP.NET MVC routes.  There's no way that the ASP.NET web forms runtime (ASPX) would know how to take your data (17) and map it to the pollId parameter.

Comment: I've read that it is possible with asp.net, I just can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `success` handler to your options hash that are passed into `$.ajax`, something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "PollManager.aspx/DeletePoll",
        data: "17",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }             
    });
```

Comment: thanks, forgot all about that :) The alert is just showing an empty box

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `[ScriptMethod]`, Or change it to `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]` because you don't want XML formatted response. You want JSON response, don't you?

Also I don't know how it serializes a string object, but you might want to also try returning an object that you define.  Like `new SomeResponseObject(){ MyResponseText="some text" }`

Then if you return that object, in javaScript you should be able to access it like this `data.MyResponseText`

Comment: Actually I finally got it working, and it does require the [ScriptMethod] to work.

Comment: Oh nice.  Can you briefly share what you did to make it work? I'm curious too, I think we could all learn from it.